# Не загружается вид laravel 5.7, ошибка Too few arguments to function e(), 0 passed in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.7

Я сделал обычный маршрут, чтобы просто возвращал мне вид через контроллер (если сделать функцию для маршрута и туда добавить: `return view('manager.addworker');` - не исправит ошибку).
Вот сам маршрут:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/manager/create/staff/','ViewController@show');
```

Соответственно в самом контроллере прописал:

```
`namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class ViewController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        if (View::exists('manager.addworker')) 
        {
            return view('manager.addworker');
        }
        else 
        {
            echo('вид отсутствует');
        }
    }
}`
```

На что мне выдаёт ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём, если использовать виды в корне папки `views`, например: `return view('welcome');` - то всё успешно работает. Название папок проверял, проверял, пробовал загонять вид в переменную и возвращать саму переменную, ничего не помогает, выводит ту же ошибку.

Comment: А попробуйте в роуте вместо контроллера просто отобразить вид `function () {
    return view('manager.addworker');
}`

Comment: И попробуйте сбросить кэш views `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Ошибка возникает в шаблоне, как именно вы его вызываете - неважно. Об этом говорит сама ошибка.

Comment: Пробовал в маршруте вид возвращать. С этого, как раз и начинал, выводило эту же ошибку, поэтому написал контроллер в надежде её исправить, но, увы, не помогло.

Comment: @VladislavFinder а есть указать не match а просто гет?

Comment: @AntonKucenko, не помогло. И `any` пробовал.

Comment: @Alexxosipov, я пробовал менять сам blade шаблон, чтобы там было почти пусто, только кусок HTML кода без blade элементов- не помогло. И очистка кэша не помогла.

Comment: Покажите код уже отрендеренного view (он хранится в папке `storage/framework/views`, название файла в ошибке)

Comment: @Alexxosipov я исправил ошибку тем, что вытянул вид из папки просто кинул её в корень, ну и прописал `return view('addworker');` в теле функции маршрута без использования контроллера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я исправил ошибку тем, что вытянул вид из папки просто кинул её в корень, ну и прописал return view('addworker'); в теле функции маршрута без использования контроллера. Метод не самый лучший, но сработал.

Answer (score 0):

У меня было подобное, когда в файле шаблона был такой комментарий:

`{{ /* A comment here */ }}`

и Blade конвертировал его в:

`<?php echo e(/* A comment here */); ?>`

Комментарий же в файле Blade должен быть таким:

`{{-- A comment here --}}`